# Using Object to execute SQL statements in Visual Studio

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access

I apologize if my question is simple, but I have done a lot of looking on the Internet and I am having trouble finding a solution.

I have a database connected to Visual Studio where I used the "Connect to Database..." wizard to establish the connection.  In the Server Explorer in Visual Studio, I see I have a Data Connection called "newreptDBtest.accdb", and a Server named Mandrew.

Basically I would like to execute SQL statements on this database when clicking a button.  So I have a button on a form, and it has the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=Mandrew;Initial Catalog=newreptDBtest.accdb"
    Try
        sqlconn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error on connection")
    End Try
    If sqlconn.State = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Success!")
    End If
End Sub
```

In General Declarations, I have:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Perhaps because it's not a SQL database?  I'm not sure.  Either way, I have not been able to achieve the "Success!" from the MessageBox.  Once I've gotten that, I'm sure I can figure out how to create SQL statements to return certain rows or single pieces of information.

In the newreptDBtest, the table I'd like to be executing queries on is called newrept, and the connection string to the database is:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\newreptDBtest.accdb"
```

tl;dr:

How do I use an object (such as a button) to execute SQL queries on a table inside a database already connected to my project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes that you need to use for accessing an MS Access database file are in the [System.Data.OleDb namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Try this:

```
Dim ConnString As String = "server=Mandrew;Initial Catalog=newreptDBtest.accdb"
Dim SqlString As String = "put your query here, e.g. Select * From Contacts"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
conn.Open()
Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  While reader.Read()
    'access the data using the reader, e.g. reader("ColumnName")
  End While
End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Taken from [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access)

Obviously, you will need to modify it to fit your query but this hightlights the fact that you need to use `OleDbConnection` to connect to an MS Access file.

Comment: I imported the namespace, and had to modify the ConnString to include a provider, so I added:
Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=...
But I get an "Invalid authorization specification" exception on the conn.Open() line... Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to specify the username and password in the connection string by adding uid=Username;pwd=password; See http://www.sqlstrings.com/MS-Access-connection-strings.htm more info on connectionstrings. Note, I don't think you can use SQLOLEDB provider for Access db.

Comment: Yea, I just realized about the provider.  I now changed the connection string to this:
    `Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;server=Mandrew;Data Source='C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\newreptDBtest.accdb'"`
And I'm getting an error: "Could not find installable ISAM."  And oddly enough, removing the "server=Mandrew;" part let the code run with no errors.  I don't have it set to do anything in the `While reader.Read()` loop, but I didn't get any errors!

Comment: @SuperXero Again, Server is not valid entry in for the provider that you are using. See the link I have posted in the previous comment. If your question is answered please don't forget to click the green tick next to the answer :)

Comment: So I modified the query to provide just one result, and in the While reader.Read loop I put a message box popping up to say success, thus everything is working correctly now!  Thanks so much!